# Is there a way to change a local typed constant from *outside* the routine it's declared in?

Tags: delphi, scope, static-variables

Please note that this is just a thought experiment.
I know global (static) vars are bad and breaking scope is a bad idea in any case.

Consider the following code:

```
function IsItChanged: integer;
const
  CanIBeChanged: integer = 0;
begin
  Result:= CanIBeChanged; 
end;
```

Assuming writable constants have been enabled, how can I change the value of `CanIBeChanged` from outside the scope of the function it's declared in?

PS No I do not intend to ever use this code it's just a question out of interest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it can only be done by leaking a pointer to the writeable typed constant. Here is an example that takes a rather convoluted way to print the number of the beast:

```
program NaughtyNaughtyVeryNaughty;{$J+}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
procedure Test(out MyPrivatesExposed: PInteger);
const
  I: Integer=665;
begin
  MyPrivatesExposed := @I;
  inc(I);
end;

var
  I: PInteger;
begin
  Test(I);
  Writeln(I^);
  Readln;
end.
```

Since the scope of a local is confined to the function in which it is defined, the approach outlined above is the only possible solution.

Comment: What's the livetime of a local writable const? Until the code leaves the method(like a normal local variable), or is it shared? In the first case your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It's a truly bizarre construct. They are really global variables. Equivalent to C locals with static storage.

Comment: I was vaguely remembering something like that, but wasn't sure anymore.

Comment: It can appear even more naughty if you move `inc(I)` to `inc(I^);` right after `Test(I);`

Comment: @kobik: You might be right but there's hardly a point in seeking more naughtiness after one's privates are exposed.

Comment: @AndriyM, one thing is to expose them... but to actually INC them, is a greater naughtiness.

Comment: They arent really a global variables, such statement is equivalent to dry water or something, they just residing in the DATA segment.